# How to use emma for jar files

Tags: java, jar, code-coverage, emma

How do I run use emma with a jar file. I downloaded emma.jar and another jar for testing purpose (MySQLConnector.jar). I placed both the jars in the same folder and tried to give this command

```
java -cp emma.jar emmarun -jar MySQLConnector.jar
```

. But I got an error saying

> emmarun: failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
>
> [C:\Documetings\Administrator\Desktop\jars\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar]

How do I solve this problem!!.. ANy other methods to test code coverage are also welcome!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We only can instrument *executable* jars. Which makes sense: emma needs something to run. And the connector library simply isn't executable: it's manifest file does not have the `Main-Class` attribute and I guess, the library does not contain a class with a `main` method too.

Rethink what you really want to test. The coverage report will show which lines of code have been executed during a (test) run. It does not tell us, which lines are *executable*.

Find yourself an executable jar and then you should see valid result.

Comment: As I said - choose a jar that is *executable*. Not a "library", take an "application".